# Is there a way to track changes to a folder in github?

Tags: github

I work with 5 other developers and on average, there's about 100 commits a day. I want to monitor some code which no other developer is supposed to touch, but they might.

Is there a way in github that I can track changes to a particular folder of code? So if a change is made, somehow I am alerted?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a [post-receive hook on your Github repo](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks) (you can [test it too](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-webhooks)), in order to call a server of yours in which you would:

- update a local repo
- `git diff HEAD..HEAD^`
- monitor the differences introduces by that latest update (and raise an alert if certain files has changed)